# UIActionSheet with Datepicker in IOS8 Xamarin Replacement

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have been set to make some changes to a Xamarin IOS project (which I am total new to), and I quickly found out, that our project does not work as it should.

```
            // save our uiview owner
        this._owner = owner;

        // configure the title label
        _titleLabel.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        _titleLabel.TextColor = Colors.backgroundcolor;
        _titleLabel.Font = Fonts.HelveticaNeueLight();

        // configure the done button
        _doneButton.SetTitle("OK", UIControlState.Normal);
        _doneButton.TouchUpInside += (s, e) => { _actionSheet.DismissWithClickedButtonIndex(0, true); };
        _doneButton.SetTitleColor(Colors.backgroundcolor, UIControlState.Normal);
        _doneButton.SetFont(eFontType.HelveticaNeue_Light, 14);

        // create + configure the action sheet
        _actionSheet = new UIActionSheet() { Style = UIActionSheetStyle.BlackTranslucent };
        _actionSheet.Clicked += (s, e) => { Console.WriteLine("Clicked on item {0}", e.ButtonIndex); };

        // add our controls to the action sheet
        _actionSheet.AddSubview(picker);
        _actionSheet.AddSubview(_titleLabel);
        _actionSheet.AddSubview (_doneButton);
```

^this was how it was created, and added some label, button and a datepicker. 
We were using a UIActionSheet to show a Datepicker. But as I can see, IOS8 does not support this way to handle it anymore.
And I am clueless how we can make it work with UIAlertController - I cannot find any good examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see this post from the Xamarin Forums [iOS 8 Datepicker](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/24128/ios-8-datepicker)

To quote,

> Now the Actionsheet can't add Subviews anymore

So here is a Github link for a replacement for the ActionSheet Datepicker. I just implemented this in my app and its working well. [Github Replacement](https://github.com/SharpMobileCode/ModalPickerViewController)

In the forum post there is a step by step link to integrate into your project.

Comment: any link to accomplish this with iOS 7